# MYSQL how to fill columns in sequence

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 4 columns. I want to insert value B into each column in sequence. I don't want to fill all columns at once.

The below query fills both col3 and col4 if it finds a value in col2. I don't want that.

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2)
VALUES ('a','b')
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE col3='b', col4='b'
```

The below query doesn't work for obvious reasons but how can I update the columns in sequence if the previous column contains data?

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2)
VALUES ('a','b')
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE col3='b'
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE col4='b'
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. A duplicate key event either happens or doesn't happen, it doesn't play out in stages.

Comment: Perhaps its misleading about the duplicate key. I just want to update a column and if a value exists, update the next column, if value exists, update the last column...

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to populate values that aren't already assigned:

```
... UPDATE col3=IFNULL(col3, 'b'),
  col4=IFNULL(col4, 'b'),
```

Or even better, re-write it to do it as a full insert if you mean to assign `col3` and `col4` regardless:

```
INSERT INTO _table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ('a', 'a', 'b', 'b')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col3=IFNULL(col3, VALUES(col3)),
    col4=IFNULL(col4, VALUES(col4))
```